# Sending Push commands to IP Phone

Tags: xml, cisco, cisco-axl

Can anyone help with the below, trying to get the background screenshot of a Cisco IP Phone using the Execute command /CGI/Screenshot

### Device: `Cisco IP Phone 7962G`

### System version: `11.0.1.22900-14`

Device is associated to the End User

Auth URL = `http://<x.x.x.x>:8082/InformaCast/phone/auth`

Going directly to 
http://10.40.7.130/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.configuration

After prompt for User/Pass

Works - Network Configuration/Cisco Unified IP Phone CP-7962G - Displays information

Going to http://172.09.0.11/ccmcip/authenticate.jspUserID=userID&Password=12345&devicename=SEP0000000000000

Authorized

**However**

Going to http://10.40.7.130/CGI/Screenshot

```
<CiscoIPPhoneError Number="4"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CUCM has the Authentication URL configured to point to an Informacast host, as you seem to show, then that's where the phone will attempt to athenticate any inbound POST requests.

You can probably see how/if Informacast is authenticating the user in question by testing something like:

```
http://<x.x.x.x>:8082/InformaCast/phone/authUserID=userID&Password=12345&devicename=SEP0000000000000
```

I suspect you will find that the response is not 'AUTHENTICATE', in which case you'll need to investigate the Informacast system to find out how you can get it to either authenticate the user(s) as needed (typically I believe Informacast can be configured to redirect any auth requests for users it doesn't handle itself back to the CUCM Authentication URL.)

It may be useful to connect a PC to the phone's extra switch port on the back, and use Wireshark/tcpdump to view the raw HTTP traffic generated by the phone - this should could you some clues about where the auth attempt is being sent/redirected, and how the various services are responding.